# Jquery scroll doesn't execute correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with a big but simple script. I need to highlight some divs' background when clicking on a button. Everything works correctly until i add a scroll function to add other colouring rules.

I have the following javascript code on scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {   
        var $top1 = $('.container_img_banchi_idraulici').offset().top + 330;
        var $top_bpf = $('#BPF-T3000').offset().top -100;



             if (($(window).scrollTop()>$top_bpf) && $('.hidden_combinati').css("display") == "block")   
            {
             color_bpf_t3000();
            }

             if (($(window).scrollTop()<$top_bpf) && $('.hidden_combinati').css("display") == "block")    
            {

             no_color_bpf();
            }
```

and the other functions code:

**COLOR_BPF:**

```
function color_bpf_t3000(){         

            for (i = 0; i<BPF_T3000.length; i++){               
                $('#'+BPF_T3000[i]+'.rettangolo_test').animate({ backgroundColor: color_green });
                $('#'+BPF_T3000[i]+' + a').css('font-weight', 'bold');          
            }
            for (i = 0; i<BPF_T3000_optional.length; i++){              
                $('#'+BPF_T3000_optional[i]+'.rettangolo_test').animate({ backgroundColor: color_yellow });
                $('#'+BPF_T3000_optional[i]+' + a').css('font-weight', 'bold');         
            }

        }
```

**NO_COLOR**

```
function decolora_bpf(){
            reset_colors();                 
            for (i = 0; i<combinati.length; i++){               
                $('#'+combinati[i]+'.rettangolo_test').animate({ backgroundColor: color_green });
                $('#'+combinati[i]+' + a').css('font-weight', 'bold');          
            }
        }
```

**RESET_COLOR**

```
function resetta_colori(){
            $('.rettangolo_test').css('background-color', color_white);
            $('.rettangolo_test + a').css('font-weight', 'normal');
        }
```

What happens is that no_color_bpf is executed even when .hidden_combinati has display none.

**BUT if i write code like**

```
             if (($(window).scrollTop()<$top_bpf) && $('.hidden_combinati').css("display") == "block")    
            {
            alert("hello"); 
             no_color_bpf();
            }
```

all works fine.

It seems that the function is executed before display goes none. I tried to delay the function with .delay() and other methods but no way to solve.

Any advice?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**
var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();

```
console.log("scrolltop "+scrolltop); 
            console.log("top_Btp "+top_bpf); 
            console.log("display " +$('.hidden_combinati').css("display"));
            console.log("if " + scrolltop<top_bpf && $('.hidden_combinati').is(':visible'));
            console.log("if2 " +scrolltop < top_bpf);
            console.log("if2 " +scrolltop > top_bpf);
```

The output is like:

```
top_Btp 911 
display block 
false 
false 
false 
scrolltop 506 
top_Btp 911 
display block 
false 
false 
false 
scrolltop 507 
top_Btp 911 
display block 
false 
false 
false
```

And so on even when scrollTop goes over Top_bpt.

What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I find it extremely usefull to debug my code using console.log() to examine what goes wrong. I would run a

`console.log($(window).scrollTop());`
`console.log($top_bpf);`
`console.log($('.hidden_combinati').css("display"));`

first, to be sure of what makes the condition true.

console.log() outputs to javascript console which is found at "inspect element" in Chrome and "firebug" at firefox.

Comment: Thanks alekos, very useful, i didn't know that. The problem now is that my if never goes on true. if i print out:

Comment: You mean you are comparing 2 values and both comparisons go false?

Comment: Yes, just look to the last 2 console.log, first condition is scrolltop < top_bpf and second is scrolltop > top_bpf but is always false...

Comment: Try `parseInt(scrolltop,10) > parseInt(top_bpf,10)` and `parseInt(scrolltop,10) < parseInt(top_bpf,10)`

Comment: Always both false :-( you can see this at http://test.giussanionline.it/en/prodotti/banchi_idraulici.php cant really understand why it does not work! P.s. click on combined to see different values

Comment: So, i checked again, now condition works, it seems that you can't write nothing beforse outputing boolean result. Anyway i found the problem, on window.scroll the pc seems to go too slow and when i scroll fast it goes on tilt, if i just scroll slowly the code works. Any advice for this? really thanks!